# jQuery hide input with two events - on click and blur?

Tags: jquery, onclick, blur

I'm trying to get an input field to show and hide via css transitions. I have the css and html portion figured out. I'd like the input to toggle show/hide when a div is clicked. I would also like it to hide if the input loses focus (blur).

I have it almost working except when clicking the div a second time. Blur fires before the click event. So, the blur event removes the class but the click event re-applies the class. I believe the standard order is blur is first. So, it is essentially working as expected, just not what is desired.

**The states that work.**

1. Click div and input reveals applying focus so the user can start typing.
2. Click outside of input and the input hides removing focus.

**The state that doesn't work**

1. Click the div a second time to hide the input. The blur event fires since you are clicking outside the input. And, the click event re-applies the class. So, it starts to hide, but then reveals itself.

I'm sure there is a way to achieve this. My brain is mush at the moment. Any help is appreciated.

```
$('.clickme').on({
        click: function() {

            $('.wrapper').toggleClass("left");
            if ( $(".wrapper").hasClass("reveal") ) {
                $('.large input').focus();
            }

        }

    });
    $('.large input').on({ blur: function() {
            $('.wrapper').removeClass("reveal");

        }

    });
```

Comment: would you be so kind as to add a fiddle?  I think you might need to look into ADDING the class too.  Your code seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If blur fires before click, you can prevent event bubbling with this in your blur handler:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```